# How to fix this MongoDB aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb

The collection structure looks like this:

```
[{  
      "id":"1",
      "firstname":"Wilhelm",
      "surname":"Röntgen",
      "born":"1845-03-27",
      "Country":"Prussia (now Germany)",
      "bornCountryCode":"DE",
      "City":"Lennep (now Remscheid)",
      "gender":"male",
      "prizes":[  
         {  
            "year":"1901",
            "category":"physics",
            "share":"1",
            "motivation":"\"in recognition of the extraordinary services he has rendered by the discovery of the remarkable rays subsequently named after him\"",
            "affiliations":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Munich University",
                  "city":"Munich",
                  "country":"Germany"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
}]
```

I am a new user of mongodb. 
I want to find all cities in US that are the city of at least 10 user lived in. 
This is the code I wrote but it doesn't show the result...
Can someone help me to fix it? Thank you...

```
db.database.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$City",count:{$sum:1}},
{$match:{$and:[{count:{$gt:10}}, {Country: "US"}]}}]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First small problem is you are missing a closing `}` on line 2, should be:

```
{$group:{_id:"$City",count:{$sum:1}}},
```

Now if you run just the `$group` stage of your pipeline, you will get results like this:

```
{ "_id" : "Lennep (now Remscheid)", "count" : 1 }
```

As you can see the `Country` field is missing. That's why the `$match` stage returns no results.

So a better approach is to move the filter by `Country` to the start, before the `$group` stage.

```
db.database.aggregate([
  {$match:{Country: "US"}},
  {$group:{_id:"$City",count:{$sum:1}}},
  {$match:{count:{$gte:10}}}
])
```

Also note I changed `{$gt:10}` to `{$gte:10}` as you mentioned "at least 10".

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! While starting doing this, I also have a concern about why I can use two match operation here?

Comment: You’re welcome! That’s not a problem, the docs state “Pipeline stages can appear multiple times in the pipeline” https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: Thank you again! I saw some StackOverflow posts said there are only one match and one group operation allowed...But now, I know that statement is wrong...